# Print a square!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Print this text:

```
 _________
|         |
|         |
|         |
|_________|
```

Shortest code wins. Notice the space at the start of the first line.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Is there anything that makes this challenge interesting compared to all the other [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenges we already have?

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
" "+($x="_"*9)
,"|$(" "*9)|"*3
"|$x|"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBSVtDpcJWKV5Jy1KTS0epRkUDKAZk1yhpGXMBuRU1Sv//AwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
←×⁵_↑⁴ ×⁵_‖Ｏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJzWtREchJDM3tVjDVEdBKV5JU9OaCyoZWqCjYALnKikowdnoGoJS03JSk0v8y1KLchILNDSt////r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Sadly the vertical direction is insufficiently symmetric to make it worthwhile reflecting. Explanation:

```
←×⁵_
```

Print 5 `_`s, leaving the cursor to the left of the first `_`. This makes up half of the bottom of the square.

```
↑⁴
```

Print 4 `|`s upwards, making the left of the square.

```
 ×⁵_
```

Print a space and 5 `_`s, making half of the top of the square.

```
‖Ｏ
```

Reflect to complete the square.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
<3 9$LF[9!:7' |_'#~6 4 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfmpyRr6RXa2WgYGXw38ZYwVLFxy3aUtHKXF2hJl5duc5MwUTB8P9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｉ×⁹-x~‰‟│
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjI5JUQ3JXUyMDc5LXglN0UldTIwMzAldTIwMUYldTI1MDI_,v=8)

Compression. Less boring 12-byte answer:

```
２|＊５_×＋⇵ ∔↕╪

2|*           repeat "|" vertically 2 times
   5_×        repeat "_" horizontally 5 times
      +       add the two together horizontally
       ⇵      reverse the canvas vertically
         ∔    prepend a space (because otherwise it glitches out :|)
          ↕   reverse vertically, moving the underscores up
           ╪  quad-palindromize, moving underscores as needed
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjEyJTdDJXVGRjBBJXVGRjE1XyVENyV1RkYwQiV1MjFGNSUyMCV1MjIxNCV1MjE5NSV1MjU2QQ__,v=8)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
ð'_9×«ð9×'|.ø4и`ð'_:»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Ab1eMvD0w@tPrwBSKnX6B3eYXJhRwJI2OrQ7v//AQ)

Comment: Dangit _Okx_.. And here I was so happy with my Canvas answer being shorter than the compression I usually use for KC challenges. +1 though, nice shorter alternative!

Comment: Btw, you can remove the `©`, since you don't use it anywhere. And the `5` should be a `4`. PS: If you want to use the Elixir rewrite instead of Python legacy, replace the `*` with `×`. Multiply with strings coincidentally works in the Python legacy version, but was never intended to. Bit of a bug disguised as 'feature'.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fixed and golfed off a byte

Comment: My biggest problem with the new 05AB1E is that the debug feature is terrible

Comment: Yeah, I can only agree on that.. I switch a lot back to the legacy in order to use `-d`. You do get a bit more information when using `--debug-stack` instead of `-d` in the Elixir rewrite version, but still not as much or as good as with the legacy debugger `-d`..

Comment: Personally I debug by putting `=` where I think there's a problem. I used to use -d... just rechecked it, but now it's seemingly worse than I remember. I used to just post debug logs as the explanation at times.

Comment: Also, random note, here's a numerical way to do it (worse than yours): `₄т*xsD1 6×+Ð)À.º»2ÝJ…_ |‡` but about 50x more convoluted.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
a=' '
for b in'_   _':print a+9*b+a;a='|'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWXUGdKy2/SCFJITNPPV5BQSFe3aqgKDOvRCFR21IrSTvRGqimRv3/fwA)

Changes the outer character from `' '` to `'|'` after the first line using an assignment, a simple trick I don't remember seeing in an ASCII art golf before.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>27</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (using compression and mirror)

```
…_ |•ʒßKèËß•3вèJ5ä».º
```

Straightforward approach.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX//@KApl8gfOKAosqSw59Lw6jDi8Of4oCiM9Cyw6hKNcOkwrsuwrr//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
…_ |        # Push string "_ |"
•ʒßKèËß•    # Push compressed integer 68865864629382
 3в         # Convert to Base-3 as list
            #  [1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0]
   è        # Index each into the string
            #  [" ","_","_","_","_","_","|"," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," "," "," "," ","|","_","_","_","_","_"]
    J       # Join all characters together
            #  " _____|     |     |     |_____"
     5ä     # Split the string into 5 equal-sized substrings
            #  [" _____","|     ","|     ","|     ","|_____"]
       »    # Join them by newlines
            #  " _____\n|     \n|     \n|     \n|_____"
        .º  # Mirror with overlap (and output implicitly)
            #  " _________ \n|         |\n|         |\n|         |\n|_________|\n"
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•ʒßKèËß•3в` is `[1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0]`.

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>28</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (using the Canvas)

```
'_9∍ð'|4∍JDðKðJŽWêSÌsŽ9¦SΛ
```

I like this approach a lot more, but unfortunately it's a bit longer.. This approach uses [the Canvas builtin `Λ`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPd7yUUfv4Q3qNSZA2svl8Abvwxu8ju4NP7wq@HBP8dG9loeWBZ@b/f8/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
'_9∍      '# Push string "_" and enlarge it to size 9: "_________"
ð          # Push a space character
'|4∍      '# Push string "|" and enlarge it to size 4: "||||"
J          # Join the entire stack together to a single string
D          # Duplicate it
ðK         # Remove the space
ð          # Push a space character
J          # Join all the entire stack together to a single string
           # (We now have "_________ ||||_________|||| ")
ŽWê        # Push compressed integer 8393
   S       # Convert it to a list of digits: [8,3,9,3]
    Ì      # Add 2 to each: [10,5,11,5]
s          # Swap the list and string on the stack
Ž9¦        # Push compressed integer 2460
   S       # Convert it to a list of digits: [2,4,6,0]
Λ          # Use the Canvas with options (and output immediately implicitly):
           #  [10,5,11,5] as lengths
           #  "_________ ||||_________|||| " as string to draw
           #  [2,4,6,0] as directions, which is [left,down,right,up] respectively
```

Here a few alternatives for creating the strings (`'_9∍ð'|4∍JDðKðJ`) with the same amount of bytes:

- `ð'|4×'_5×©Jû®ûì`: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX//8OwJ3w0w5cnXzXDl8KpSsO7wq7Du8Osxb1Xw6pTw4xzxb05wqZTzpv//w)
- `'_9∍Dðs'|4∍.øðJ`: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPd7yUUevy@ENxeo1JkCW3uEdhzd4Hd0bfnhV8OGe4qN7LQ8tCz43@/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 11, 57 bytes

```java
v->" _________\n"+"|         |\n".repeat(3)+"|_________|"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PU5BCsIwELz3FUtOCdJcPBb9gb0IXlRkTaOkpmlptgGxfXtMsXUOCzOzzEyNAfO6ekVl0Xs4oHGfDMA40v0DlYZypgBH6o17guKn1lQQRJHUKUvHE5JRUIKDHcSQ7xncVlwc27ARVoyJy153GolvRXL@jyOLxRzWDXebwpbMMFc1aRH/tZ@vgGKZ8/akG9kOJLtkkXXcScXdYK1Ytk3xCw)

I don't think this requires an explanation.. >.>

Comment: Hi, I am new to golfing. Can you explain where is the print statement here? Thank for your help.

Comment: @isaace Hi there and welcome to PPCG! We have some default rules that apply to all challenges (unless **_explicitly_** stated differently). For example, [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/52210) are forbidden by default; and you are allowed to use [any default I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/52210). This means that you are allowed to use functions instead of full programs, and you're also allowed to return a string instead of printing something to STDOUT directly. Since Java is pretty verbose, I use both those alternatives in my answer.

Comment: ok, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @isaace The shortest full program that prints directly to STDOUT would have been `interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(" _________\n"+"|         |\n".repeat(3)+"|_________|");}}`. Since all Java programs need a mandatory main method and enclosing class/interface, it's (almost) always shorter to use a (Java 8+ lambda) function instead. In addition, it's shorter to return a String instead of printing with `System.out.print` in this case. Hope that clears it up a bit. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>54</s>, <s>53</s>, <s>50</s>, 48 bytes

```
print' '+'_'*9+'\n|         |'*3+'\n|_________|'
```

-1 Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

-3 Thanks to Okx

-2 Thanks to Vedant Kandoi

Comment: You can remove the trailing space on the first line (`+' \n'` to `+'\n'`) to save a byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen whoops! Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: 50 bytes if you move around the newlines: `print' '+'_'*9+('\n|'+' '*9+'|')*4+'\n|'+'_'*9+'|'`

Comment: 48 bytes: `print' '+'_'*9+'\n|         |'*5+'\n|_________|'`, 9 spaces between `|` and `|`

Comment: @Okx ahh good spot!

Comment: @VedantKandoi thanks loads!

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
“5＋║³╵∑O：E`}7╴？Ｂ<‟│
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMDFDNSV1RkYwQiV1MjU1MSVCMyV1MjU3NSV1MjIxMU8ldUZGMUFFJTYwJTdENyV1MjU3NCV1RkYxRiV1RkYyMiUzQyV1MjAxRiV1MjUwMg__,v=8)

Comment: oh, there was already a canvas compression answer.. Either way the input string to compression I gave was `" _____¶|¶|¶|¶|_____"` - trailing spaces are automatically added, and splitting the input in multiple lines just worsens its compression ability

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 bytes

```cs
Console.Write(" {0}\n|{1}{1}{1}{0}|","_________","         |\n|");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv1fWpyZl64QXFlckpprrZCck1hcrOCoUK1QXJJYkpmsUJafmaLgm5iZp6GpUP3fOT@vOD8nVS@8KLMkVUNJodqgNiavptqwFooMamuUdJTiYQDIVoCBGqBCJU3r/7W1/wE)

- Prints the first argument of `Console.Write()`
- `{0}` refers to the second argument (`"_________"`)
- `{1}` refers to the third argument (`"         |\n|"`).

Answer (score 2):

### [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse) - 3251 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 0
0 2 1 0 3 1 0
0 3 1 0 4 0 0
0 4 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 2 0 0
1 2 1 1 5 0 0
0 5 0 1 6 0 0
0 6 1 0 7 0 0
0 7 0 1 3 0 0
1 3 1 1 8 0 0
0 8 1 0 4 0 0
1 4 1 1 5 0 0
1 5 1 1 9 0 0
0 9 1 0 6 0 0
1 6 1 1 7 0 0
1 7 1 1 10 0 0
0 10 1 1 11 0 0
0 11 1 0 8 1 0
1 8 1 0 9 1 0
1 9 1 0 10 1 0
1 10 1 0 11 1 0
1 11 1 1 12 1 0
1 12 1 0 13 1 0
1 13 1 1 14 1 0
1 14 1 0 15 1 0
1 15 1 1 16 1 0
1 16 1 1 17 0 0
1 17 0 1 18 0 0
1 18 1 1 19 0 0
1 19 0 0 20 0 0
1 20 1 0 12 0 0
0 12 0 0 21 0 0
1 21 1 0 22 0 0
1 22 0 0 13 0 0
0 13 0 0 23 0 0
1 23 0 0 14 1 0
0 14 0 1 15 0 0
0 15 1 0 16 0 0
0 16 0 1 24 0 0
1 24 1 1 17 0 0
0 17 1 0 25 0 0
1 25 1 1 26 0 0
1 26 1 1 18 0 0
0 18 1 0 27 0 0
1 27 1 1 28 0 0
1 28 1 1 29 0 0
1 29 1 1 19 0 0
0 19 1 1 30 0 0
1 30 0 0 31 1 0
1 31 0 0 32 0 0
1 32 0 0 33 0 0
1 33 0 0 34 0 0
1 34 1 0 35 0 0
1 35 0 0 20 1 0
0 20 0 1 21 1 0
0 21 0 1 36 1 0
1 36 1 1 22 1 0
0 22 0 1 23 1 0
0 23 0 0 24 1 0
0 24 0 1 25 1 0
0 25 0 0 26 1 0
0 26 0 1 27 1 0
0 27 1 1 28 0 0
0 28 1 0 37 0 0
1 37 1 0 29 0 0
0 29 1 0 38 0 0
1 38 1 0 30 0 0
0 30 1 0 31 1 0
0 31 0 1 39 0 0
1 39 0 0 32 0 0
0 32 0 1 33 0 0
0 33 0 1 40 0 0
1 40 0 0 34 0 0
0 34 0 1 35 0 0
0 35 0 1 41 0 0
1 41 0 0 36 0 0
0 36 0 1 37 0 0
0 37 0 1 42 0 0
1 42 1 1 43 0 0
1 43 0 1 38 0 0
0 38 1 0 39 1 0
0 39 1 1 44 0 0
1 44 0 0 45 0 0
1 45 1 0 46 0 0
1 46 1 0 40 0 0
0 40 1 0 41 0 0
0 41 1 0 42 0 0
0 42 1 0 43 1 0
0 43 0 1 47 0 0
1 47 0 0 44 0 0
0 44 0 1 45 0 0
0 45 0 1 48 0 0
1 48 1 1 49 0 0
1 49 0 0 50 0 0
1 50 1 1 46 0 0
0 46 0 1 51 0 0
1 51 0 1 52 0 0
1 52 0 0 47 1 0
0 47 0 0 48 1 0
0 48 0 1 49 1 0
0 49 0 0 50 1 0
0 50 0 1 51 1 0
0 51 0 0 52 1 0
0 52 0 1 53 1 0
0 53 0 0 54 1 0
0 54 0 1 55 1 0
0 55 1 1 56 0 0
0 56 1 0 53 0 0
1 53 1 0 57 0 0
0 57 1 0 54 0 0
1 54 1 0 58 0 0
0 58 1 0 59 1 0
0 59 0 1 55 0 0
1 55 0 0 60 0 0
0 60 0 1 61 0 0
0 61 0 1 56 0 0
1 56 0 0 62 0 0
0 62 0 1 63 0 0
0 63 0 1 57 0 0
1 57 0 0 64 0 0
0 64 0 1 65 0 0
0 65 0 1 58 0 0
1 58 1 1 59 0 0
1 59 0 1 66 0 0
0 66 1 0 67 1 0
0 67 1 1 60 0 0
1 60 0 0 61 0 0
1 61 1 0 62 0 0
1 62 1 0 68 0 0
0 68 1 0 69 0 0
0 69 1 0 70 0 0
0 70 1 0 71 1 0
0 71 0 1 63 0 0
1 63 0 0 72 0 0
0 72 0 1 73 0 0
0 73 0 1 64 0 0
1 64 1 1 65 0 0
1 65 0 0 66 0 0
1 66 1 1 74 0 0
0 74 0 1 67 0 0
1 67 0 1 68 0 0
1 68 0 0 75 1 0
0 75 0 0 76 1 0
0 76 0 1 77 1 0
0 77 0 0 78 1 0
0 78 0 1 79 1 0
0 79 0 0 80 1 0
0 80 0 1 81 1 0
0 81 0 0 82 1 0
0 82 0 1 83 1 0
0 83 1 1 84 0 0
0 84 1 0 69 0 0
1 69 1 0 85 0 0
0 85 1 0 70 0 0
1 70 1 0 86 0 0
0 86 1 0 87 1 0
0 87 0 1 71 0 0
1 71 0 0 88 0 0
0 88 0 1 89 0 0
0 89 0 1 72 0 0
1 72 0 0 90 0 0
0 90 0 1 91 0 0
0 91 0 1 73 0 0
1 73 0 0 92 0 0
0 92 0 1 93 0 0
0 93 0 1 74 0 0
1 74 1 1 75 0 0
1 75 0 1 94 0 0
0 94 1 0 95 1 0
0 95 1 1 76 0 0
1 76 0 0 77 0 0
1 77 1 0 78 0 0
1 78 1 0 96 0 0
0 96 1 0 97 0 0
0 97 1 0 98 0 0
0 98 1 0 99 1 0
0 99 0 1 79 0 0
1 79 1 1 80 0 0
1 80 0 0 81 0 0
1 81 1 1 100 0 0
0 100 0 1 82 0 0
1 82 1 1 83 0 0
1 83 1 1 84 0 0
1 84 1 1 101 0 0
0 101 1 1 102 0 0
0 102 1 0 85 1 0
1 85 1 0 86 1 0
1 86 1 0 87 1 0
1 87 1 0 88 1 0
1 88 1 1 89 1 0
1 89 1 0 90 1 0
1 90 1 1 91 1 0
1 91 1 0 92 1 0
1 92 1 1 93 1 0
1 93 1 1 94 0 0
1 94 1 1 95 0 0
1 95 0 1 96 0 0
1 96 0 0 103 0 0
0 103 0 0 97 0 0
1 97 1 0 98 0 0
1 98 1 0 99 0 0
1 99 1 0 104 0 0
0 104 1 0 100 1 1
```

Made with the help of ASCII_only's program generator.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 27 bytes

```
'_9*_3{'|_ 9*▌+\}'|_@++]n \
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1893lIr3rhavSZewVLr0bQe7ZhaINtBWzs2TyHm////AA)

Pretty much the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 54 bytes

As with [Kevin's Java solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176783/58974), the boring option ended up being the shortest :\

```
_=>` _________
${`|         |
`.repeat(3)}|_________|`
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP97WLkEhHga4VKoTahRgoIYrQa8otSA1sUTDWLO2Bq6qJuG/poam5n8A)

---

### Alternative, 59 bytes

```
_=>` _
| |
| |
| |
|_|`.replace(/../g,x=>x.padEnd(10,x[1]))
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP97WLkEhnqtGoQaB42sS9IpSC3ISk1M19PX09NN1KmztKvQKElNc81I0DA10KqINYzU1/2tqAAkA)

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP97WLkEhHga4VKqLbRNqFGCghiuhFiikXVxbA1dTk/BfU0NT8z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
ŽP—S"_| _"SŽNžS.Λ.º
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//8W9UOKAlFMiX3wgXyJTxb1Oxb5TLs6bLsK6//8)

**Explanation**

```
ŽP—S                  # push [6,5,2,5] (lengths)
    "_| _"S           # push ["_", "|", " ", "_"] (characters to print)
           ŽNžS       # push [6,0,2,2] (directions)
               .Λ     # draw to canvas without printing
                 .º   # mirror horizontally
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 59 Bytes

```
v-> " _______\n|       |\n|       |\n|       |\n|_______|"
```

Comment: Should this be embedded in a function or something?

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 53 bytes

```
prin[" _________^/"r:"|         |^/"r r"|_________|"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@7@gKDMvWkkhHgbi9JWKrJRqFGCgBiSgUKRUA1dRoxT7/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 317 bytes

```
((((((((()()()()()){}){})()){}{}){}))<>)<>((((((((({}[(((()()()){}()){}){}()])))))))))(<>{}<>)((()()()()()){})(<>()()()){<>(((((((()()()()()){}){})()){}{}){})<>)<> ((((((((((((()()()()){}){}){})))))))))(<>{}<>)((()()()()()){})<>({}[()])}<>(((((()()()()){}){}){}))((((((((((({})){}{}[()])))))))))((((()()()()){}){}){})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMGNGFQs7oWhMAMCFPTxg6I4Cqra6PhGoDSMB0amrGaMKBhY1ddC9SFbi5QHMZBGIjHZrDFChrIAFUtyHUE7ARaBHIx0HW1MDsxzUCyAMQF2R@N4iGs2v7//6/rCAA)

Not golfy at all, just a test.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <strike>31</strike> 28 bytes

```
S'_9*S++'|S9*'|++___4$.e>]N*
```

Explanation

```
S'_9*S++'|S9*'|++___4$.e>]N*     e# Whole code
S'_9*S++                         e# Push the string ' _________ '
        '|S9*'|++                e# Push the string '|         |'
                 ___             e# Duplicate it 3 times
                    4$           e# Copy the 4th stack element (' _________ ')
                      .e>        e# Combine the last '|         |' with the 
                                 e# ' _________ ' to get '|_________|'
                         ]N*     e# Join with newlines
                                 e# Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P1g93lIrWFtbvSbYUku9Rls7Pj7eREUv1S7WT@v/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
cat(gsub(0,"|         |
"," _________
000|_________|"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO9uDRJw0BHqUYBBmq4lHSUFOJhgMvAwKAGzqtR0tT8/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [BrainFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), 129 bytes

```
+++>++++++++[>++++>>>>+<<<<<-]>[>+++>++++>+<<<-]>->---->>++<.<<.........>>>.<<<<<<[>>>>.>.........<.>>.<<<<<<-]>>>>.<.........>.
```

This was my first code golf post so it isn't that optimized.

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 226 bytes

```
iisiisddddc{dd}ddsdddddccccccccc{ddddddddd}ddsicisiiic{{d}dd}iisddddccccccccc{dd}dsiiic{{d}dd}dsicisiiic{{d}dd}iisddddccccccccc{dd}dsiiic{{d}dd}dsicisiiic{{d}dd}iisddddccccccccc{dd}dsiiic{{d}dd}dsicisiiic{ddd}icccccccccd{iii}c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY5LCsAwCAVP1EMVp6VvnaV4dhsDlpyggws/80Cuk1vjOTKlMYuJOQSsHmucpm6y0mXuNUYnNznYhZ8T9aU@E5/LsMwX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é☻x+▓ïqÉ┬i╦↨|╛₧│&▬
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8202782bb28b7190c269cb177cbe9eb32616&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 93 bytes

```
--[[<+++>----->->>+++<<<]>]<<.<<-.........<.>>-->>+++[-<<.>.........<.<<.>>>>]<<.<.........>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCoBADAMfVNIXhHyk7EEFQQQPwr6/dhcU55ZMst7Lce19OzOBCJqZMBCkCiSbGukk/IWuGk0fKKefGbGYl6@WZz4)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 81 bytes

```php
while($x<9)echo str_pad(str_repeat(($l='_  | | |_|')[$x++],9),11,$l[$x++],2),"
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VCpsLDVTkzPyFYpLiuILElM0QHRRakFqYomGhkqOrXq8gkINCMbXqGtGq1Roa8fqWGrqGBrqqORAuUaaOkpcStb//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>43</s> 38 bytes

```
/~/|         |
//-/_________/ -
~~~|-|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X79Ov0YBBmq49PV19eNhQF9Bl6uurq5Gt@b/fwA)

*-5 bytes thanks to [@PkmnQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91569/pkmnq)*

Comment: Porting my FEU answer gives [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X79Ov0YBBmq49PV19eNhQF9Bl6uurq5Gt@b/fwA "/// – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [FEU](https://github.com/TryItOnline/feu), 44 bytes

```
a/ ~\n---|~|
m/-/|         |\n/~/_________/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0st/f8/UV@hLiZPV1e3pq6GK1dfV79GAQZqYvL06/TjYUA//f9/AA)